# Ubuntu not recognizing anything with RAID enabled

Tags: dual-boot, usb, raid, .desktop

I wanted to start learning how to use Ubuntu, so I created a bootable USB and proceeded to try installing Ubuntu from this USB for dual booting with Windows 10. However, when I boot with the USB, Ubuntu does not recognize any of my hard drives nor does it recognize any part of my computer, really. It doesn't seem to be able to use the wifi card or anything. This makes it hard to install because I can't access the drives. However, when I turn off RAID in the BIOS, Ubuntu works fine. The only issue with this is Windows crashes. Windows only seems to work with RAID enabled. I'm not entirely sure what to do from this point. I tried with the newest version of Ubuntu, but I've since downgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.3 since I was getting weird errors with the newest version.

Comment: Ubuntu will see your drive(s) if it is in AHCI, but before you change to that, see http://www.overclock.net/forum/20-hard-drives-storage/1227636-how-change-sata-modes-after-windows-installation.html as there should be some changes to Windows before you change to AHCI mode.

Comment: RAID vs. AHCI makes no difference to Linux.  The RAID setting is still AHCI, it just tells Windows to load the software raid driver.  Ubuntu should automatically recognize such fake raids with either the dmraid utility or mdadm.

Comment: @Terrance I'm having trouble following that tutorial because my Device Manager does not seem to be showing IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers so I don't know wwhere to uninstall my RAID. What you seem to be suggesting looks like it would work since Ubuntu does see the drivers when I boot in AHCI.

Comment: @JeffreyCarr Let me see if I can find the one I actually had to follow when I changed mine over.  When I went to AHCI I was having big issues with Windows.

Comment: @JeffreyCarr It is a little different, but they are suggesting this one is the best one to follow:  https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/650771/ide-to-ahci-windows-10/?p=4276593  I think mine was Windows 7 when I did it.

Comment: Please see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on/963100#963100. Please remember to vote for it if it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Terrance Your solution worked with the second link perfectly!

Comment: @JeffreyCarr Glad it helped!  Actually, those same steps are in heynnema's linked solution.  =)