# Dual Boot Windows 10 and Kubuntu - SATA AHCI vs RAID [error]

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, raid, ahci

I dual installed Kubuntu on a computer with Windows 10, grub is on `/dev/sda` while the Windows boot manager is on `/nvmesomethingsomething`.

To install it, I had to set SATA from RAID to AHCI in the UEFI BIOS Setup. With SATA AHCI the boot of Kubuntu works. But when I try to boot into Windows, I get a BSOD with `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`.

If in UEFI, and I select RAID instead of AHCI, I can boot into Windows, but Kubuntu's boot process results in me ending up in an [`initramfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) terminal.

So I can get only one or the other, but never both working systems.
Is there any solution?

Comment: You can install AHCI drivers in Windows, you should do that first before changing to AHCI to avoid the issue you are having. That is really a Windows issue, not directly related to Ubuntu.

Comment: which os did you install first and which drive (kubuntu drive, windows M2 or both?) were plugged in when you installed them?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! you might find [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on?rq=1) useful.

Comment: @tatsu I have exactly the same case. Windows 10 preinstalled, then I install Debian. Now I have to select RAID to load Windows or AHCI to load Debian. There is only 1 SSD drive.

Comment: @Rahn make a full question because otherwise this will get messy.

Comment: @tatsu My extending/editing got rejected...

Comment: the MBR might have a flag that prevents write. you need to google your drive's flags maybe see if you can mount the drive in read/write. and this was with a USB LiveCD?

Comment: I have the same case. When I was installing Ubuntu I switched RAID to AHCI. I followed internet article but my Windows stopped loading. Okay, I reinstalled Windows (it was clean) and then it was all right for about two months. About two days ago I tried to switch Nvidia drivers and did some updates. It worked well till evening. Next morning it loaded into initramfs console. Then I found out that with RAID setting I can use Windows and Ubuntu with AHCI. With RAID I can't see devices in LiveCD. Don't know how to handle this yet

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to update your bootmanager, because,  it points to *disappearing* path, that is:

- when Windows was installed in RAID mode, thus the bootmanager point to `/nvme` but when you switch to AHCI `/nvme` is *destroyed* and replaced by something else.
- in the same way, when you installed Kubuntu in AHCI mode, it was installed on `/dev/sda` but when you switch back to RAID, it is *destroyed*.

---

*OT: why did you need to install Kubuntu without RAID?*

Comment: For me yes. I had to change SATA option to `AHCI` to install Debian, didn't work for `RAID`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. When I was installing Ubuntu I switched RAID to AHCI. I followed internet article but my Windows stopped loading. Okay, I reinstalled Windows (it was clean) and then it was all right for about two months.

About two days ago I tried to switch Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu and did some updates. It worked well till evening. Next morning it loaded into `initramfs` console. Then I found out that with RAID setting I can use only Windows, Ubuntu loads in `initramfs` console. With AHCI I was able to run Ubuntu and Windows loads into blue screen `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`. With RAID I wasn't able to see devices from LiveCD (so I was not able to install Ubuntu in RAID).

I solved the problem switching my Windows to AHCI mode. Solution is here: http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

In short,

1. Run `cmd` from administrator,
2. `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
3. Reboot
4. Change RAID to AHCI in BIOS
5. Start Windows (it will start in safe mode)
6. Run `cmd` from administrator,
7. `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
8. Reboot.
9. Profit!

Now my Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.04 start well.