# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I cannot install Ubuntu 18.04 in my Dell Latitude 7400. I have followed four different tutorials and researched the problem, but the solutions haven't worked so far.

If I try Ubuntu from a USB it works fine, but when I install it I cannot find the disk I created neither the options on the installer to create the required partitions. From the research I did, it might be because my disk already has three principal partitions. I am not sure whether this is the problem or how to fix it.

[image: Ubuntu installation screen] 
<sup>**Ubuntu installation screen**</sup>

[image: Windows partitions in Windows]
<sup>**Windows partitions in Windows**</sup>

[image: Windows partitions visible to Ubuntu]
<sup>**Windows partitions visible to Ubuntu**</sup>

[image: Ubuntu installation type]
<sup>**Ubuntu installation type**</sup>

Comment: What you call "Windows partitions visible to Ubuntu" is another *disk* entirely, not a partittion, and is your Uubuntu usb.

Comment: /dev/sda is another disk entirely, not a partition of your boot drive, and your BIOS thinks it is a iso9660 disk, i.e., removable optical drive.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at any Dell specific instructions (Any Dell version). You typically need to update UEFI, update SSD firmware Then add AHCI driver to Windows and change RAID/Intel RST in UEFI. You have to have fast start up off in Windows (and probably bitlocker). And usually better to have fast boot off in UEFI as that assumes no configuration changes.

And if nVidia, you will need nomodeset boot parameter to boot live installer and first boot. Then install nVidia driver. Lastest version of Ubuntu will now install nVidia driver as part of install.

https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353288

UEFI install  Windows 10

[How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Details on change to AHCI in Windows:

[Install dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 and RAID on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on/963100#963100)

General UEFI install instructions & info:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295

Answer (score 2):

In gparted, change from your 250GB drive which identifies as **sda** to the 477 GB drive by clicking on the button circled in blue.   [image]

You must change from /dev/sda because dev/sda is another disk entirely, not a partition of your boot drive, and your BIOS thinks it is a iso9660 disk, i.e., a removable optical drive.

Are you able to find the 97.66 GB unallocated partition? What is its name? **That's** where you want to install Ubuntu.