# Dualbooting Ubuntu, just installed and disk space is already full

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

Full disclosure, I don't really know what I'm doing here, I just really hate Windows 10 and am trying to use Ubuntu instead. If this question has been already asked I apologize, I've been reading many other questions and either couldn't understand them or couldn't even tell if our problems were the same.

I just got a brand new Dell laptop with Windows 10 as the default operating system. I bought a SanDisk 64 GB USB drive and followed the [HowToGeek instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/214571/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-pc/) for setting up the partition and booting directly from the USB drive. I thought I was successful since my computer now automatically boots from the USB and runs Ubuntu. However, after running Ubuntu and trying to install additional programs, I checked the disk space and it only lists me as having 4.1 GB of space, with only 136 MB of space available. Since even the USB has 64 GB of space, this seems very wrong, and I thought that the whole point of partitioning the hard drive was to provide storage anyway. What is going on here, and how do I fix this?

EDIT: Here is what comes up when I run the following code:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.9 GiB, 1987817472 bytes, 3882456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 88.5 MiB, 92778496 bytes, 181208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 54.4 MiB, 57069568 bytes, 111464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 42.8 MiB, 44879872 bytes, 87656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 149.9 MiB, 157184000 bytes, 307000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 4 MiB, 4218880 bytes, 8240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.8 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 1008 KiB, 1032192 bytes, 2016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 57.3 GiB, 61505273856 bytes, 120127488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x03510df8

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 120127487 120125440 57.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/loop8: 3.7 MiB, 3825664 bytes, 7472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

After running the following code:

```
sudo df -h
```

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           775M  1.8M  773M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        58G  2.0G   56G   4% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /rofs
/cow            3.8G  3.7G  130M  97% /
tmpfs           3.8G  204M  3.6G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.8G  6.1M  3.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           775M  108K  775M   1% /run/user/999
/dev/loop1       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop2       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1066
/dev/loop3       43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop4      150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop5      4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop6       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop7      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop8      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
```

After installing inxi:

```
System:    Host: ubuntu Kernel: 5.0.0-23-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) dm: gdm3
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: Inspiron 5493 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Dell model: 0M4FW1 v: A00 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Dell v: 1.1.0 date: 08/16/2019
           Chassis: type: 10 serial: N/A
Battery    BAT0: charge: 39.9 Wh 100.0% condition: 39.9/42.0 Wh (95%)
           volts: 13.0/11.4
           model: BYD DELL 1VX1H98 serial: <filter>status: Full
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-1035G1 (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: N/A cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9523
           clock speeds: min/max: 400/3600 MHz 1: 1334 MHz 2: 964 MHz
           3: 1152 MHz 4: 863 MHz 5: 938 MHz 6: 1058 MHz 7: 1077 MHz
           8: 911 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 8a56 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:8a56
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 )
           drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.8 (compat-v: 3.1) Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Device 34c8
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:34c8
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0-23-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCIE Fast Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169 port: 3000 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8136
           IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath10k_pci bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 168c:0042
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-3: Atheros usb-ID: 001-005 chip-ID: 0cf3:e009
           IF: null-if-id state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 61.5GB (3.4% used)
           ID-1: USB /dev/sda model: Ultra_Fit size: 61.5GB
           serial: <filter> temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 3.8G used: 3.7G (97%) fs: overlay dev: N/A
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 62.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 2599
Info:      Processes: 272 Uptime: 11:00 Memory: 2562.8/7742.7MB
           Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: N/A
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201 running in gnome-terminal-) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Comment: Run `sudo fdisk -l` and post the output here by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1180343/edit) your question.

Comment: Not showing your SSD or HDD. Do you still have RAID/Intel SRT on? It should be AHCI, but if using Windows you must first install Windows AHCI driver. See this:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180258/dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-18-04/1180282#1180282

Comment: @oldfred I checked that page but I'm not sure I see what you are referring to

Comment: @DKBose I've updated the post

Comment: Maybe you still need to provide more information. The output of `df -h` may help. You could also install a small program called `inxi` using `sudo apt install inxi` and then post the output of `inxi -Fxxz` here. (The `z` ensures that indentifiable stuu like MAC addresses are masked.)

Comment: @DKBose Updated with new info

Comment: Great! Now let's hope oldfred or someone else can help you. One more bit you could provide is the link to the tutorial you followed.

Comment: See this which was in link above. https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on/963100#963100 Or it could be you have Windows fast start up still on: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation