# Install ubuntu on alienware m15 r3

Tags: dual-boot, alienware

I am about to purchase the Alienware m15 r3, and I usually dual boot all my computers, but I have seen some people experience some difficulties while trying to install ubuntu on an Alienware, and I haven't seen any posts about the new Alienware, has anyone install ubuntu on the Alienware m15 r3? If so, can you share what resources, problems you had, and the steps you followed? Thanks!!

Comment: We do not accept hardware recommendations, Bring a live usb to the store where you buy it or ask the seller online if they can test with a live usb. If new hardware does not work someone needs to file bug reports on the not working parts so it can be added.

Answer (score 2):

I just bought one and I managed to make it work with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Remember to disable RAID ON to AHCI with the safe boot procedure

[Install dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 and RAID on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on)

and to disable SECURE BOOT from BIOS setup.
After that you should be able to install and manage everything with GRUB.

I'm still having some graphic issues, but better than nothing as start.

[UPDATE]

I have no more graphic problem after following this procedure for updating the nvidia drivers
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux