# Dual boot ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 on Dell G3 3590

Tags: 18.04, dual-boot, uefi, dell, windows-10

I'm trying to dual boot my Dell G3 system that came with pre-installed windows 10. When I disabled secure boot, I couldn't even load into windows saying bitlocker encryption. I then had to find my key and input it. Then I was able to boot into windows. But when I tried installing ubuntu, I can't find my disk at all - I can only see the installation medium. Changing SATA from RAID to AHCI as said [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Inspiron-G3-15-3590-Dual-Boot-Issues-Windows-10-and-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/7432600) also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

After disabling secure boot and keying in bitlocker key, the harddisk (SSD in my case) is still encrypted. In settings, there is an option to disable encryption. After disabling that, it takes sometime to decrypt the disk. Once that is done, when I tried installing ubuntu, it worked. I could see my SSD there and the free space to install ubuntu. Remember to switch to AHCI as well. I followed the 2nd method [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/963100/775359).

**TL; DR: Disable encryption and use AHCI**