# Dual booting on RAID (Ubuntu & Windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, raid

I know it's a duplicate question but I cannot comment on any existing questions because of reputation points, so I'm opening a new one.

So according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on/) answer and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/) help page, after executing `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal` command I should be able to change BIOS settings from RAID to AHCI(which I am) and boot back to Windows safely.

The issue is that when I do change RAID to AHCI my system does not boot back into Windows - it simply prompts "No boot device found" so I cannot go back to Windows and execute `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`.

Is there any additional steps required in between?