# Run Ubuntu with RAID enabled

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, dell, raid

I am running an Ubuntu and Windows dual boot on my Dell XPS laptop. Originally I had success in running this dual boot by following the steps here: [Workaround to Install Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel RST systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems) or here: [Install dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 and RAID on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on) to run both windows and ubuntu on this computer by switching to ACHI instead of RAID, however over a few months this created significant battery problems and crashing issues, to the point where multiple hard restarts would be required after every sleep / laptop lid close to access either operating system. At first I thought this was a hardware issue and got my laptop serviced (in which they completely wiped it), and the issue was gone until I followed the same steps to set up by dual boot and then the issue reappeared a few months later. Once I switched back to RAID (by following the same steps in the link above but with the switch reversed), the crashing and battery drain problems were resolved, but I could no longer access Ubuntu.

Therefore running my laptop in ACHI is not an option, as it creates too many alternate problems that I have been unable to resolve (I have done full driver and OS reinstalls, talked to Dell support, and went through crash logs). So my question is, **is it possible to run an Ubuntu and Windows dual boot using RAID?** If I can't use Ubuntu, are there other linux distros that can run with RAID?

Comment: Properly implemented hardware RAID should be transparent to any underlying operating system and visible just as a single physical disk. The system should be not aware at all that it is running on RAID array and not a single disk device. Looks like your RAID is not a true RAID but some kind of a "poor man's RAID" which requires additional software support. That is always **expected** to cause problems. I guess replacing this with a true RAID is not possible? That would be the most reliable option.

Comment: It is intel RST which from my understanding is a software RAID, not hardware. I don't know that much about this though... what would replacing it with hardware RAID require?

Comment: Probably in a laptop this will not be possible, as it would require installing a hardware RAID controller. It is no problem in a desktop computer, but in a laptop there's no space to do that.