# How to install Ubuntu on the same NVMe SSD than Windows?

Tags: windows, ssd, usb-installation, nvme

My problem: I have a 500Gb NVMe SSD with windows installed on it and an hardDrive in my laptop (it's a lenovo y720). Every time I look to install Ubuntu 18.04.02, it can only see my 1Tb hdd.

Here are all the things I already tried:

1- I shrink my C: (NVMe drive) to be sure there is 100Gb completely free for the installation.

2-I did the command chkdsk /f (windows shell)

3- I did the command powercfg –h off to make sure Windows does not interfere. (windows shell) https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380454 (Leunam12)

4- I changed RAID SATA Controller to AHCI which my Windows did not appreciate at all. I then follow this forum wich states to update my sotrage drivers to Microsoft Storage Controller AND EVEN do that again but in safe Mode. https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/

5- On the grub's booting options I pressed 'e' to changethe line beginning by linux. I add after quiet splash "nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200" (with and without the ""). This forum said that should make my Nvme visible in my installation: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408864&s=bc394f3491f72e1886eb667346864bd3&page=2

I think that is all. Ohh and here you can see what are always my choice in the installation:Ubuntu installation without Nvme option[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSnJ7.jpg)

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? What brand SSD? Many systems need UEFI update and SSD firmware update. Make sure you have latest versions. Often easier to update with Windows.

Comment: Lenovo y720, gtx 1060, i7-7700hq, 16gb Ram, 1tb Hdd 500 Gb SSD NVMe. Brand of Samsung MZVLB512. I don't have time too look for UEFI update and SSD firmware updates tonight, but I'll do that tomorrow :)

Comment: Slightly different model, perhaps similar. Lenovo Legion Y520-15I  Installer does not detect SSD and HDD: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359208
With nVidia you will need nomodeset boot parameter to install & first boot or until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. Install nVidia
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: So I did make sure everything was update. I read what you told me, but finally her solution is to just get rid of Windows which is not a possibility in my case... However, I did notice something interesting: Even if it doesn't work for Windows, when I'm in AHCl mode, Ubuntu FINALLY see my SSD ! I still did not install it, because I want Windows to work too.. I tried the trick of going in safe mode before going in AHCl mode, but Windows still not work...

Comment: You need to install the AHCI driver into Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148120/ubuntu-18-0x-not-detecting-windows-ssd-during-installation

Comment: yeah... It didn't work. I had already tried both of the option before my post. I did it again tonight and the only thing that is hapenning is my Windows unable to reboot. I even had to uninstall last update to make it work, It wasn't working anymore even with RAID back in BIOS. I seriously feel like I tried so much thing with all the same result...

Comment: I think these are just similar instructions: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/22631-enable-ahci-windows-8-windows-10-after-installation.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by rebooting into **Safe mode *with networking***

Microsoft provides their documentation for how to [boot into safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode).

Make sure that you select: "**[Enable safe mode with networking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5425.png)**"

I then just had to restart my computer and Windows loaded AHCI mode just fine. Now I see my SSD in my Ubuntu Installation.