# Dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 & Windows 10 Pro - RST problem

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10, ahci, rst

BEFORE YOU READ THE SOLUTION:
Here is a **summary of how I solved it**: for me it really seemed to be necessary to change to AHCI in the Bios and completely reinstall windows 10 via usb, then install ubuntu afterwards. I will still accept the answer that worked for most people with similar problems but not directly like this for me. Read the comments beneath the accepted answer to get some more insight about what I tried before deciding to re-install windows.

PROBLEM:
I don't know it this is the correct place to ask for this but I have seen some similar questions on here.
I have been facing a problem with setting up a dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04 on my new Windows 10 Pro Notebook.
I looked at some general instructions on how to do this and got until installing ubuntu where I got a problem with the Intel RST Technology used on the laptop. I followed different instructions on how to switch the SATA mode to AHCI like these two: [Workaround to Install Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel RST systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems) & https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347. I tried using or not using safe boot / fast startup. I also tried installing 18.04, but it did not work either.

It was mentioned that after changing this mode, Windows might not start anymore but show these typical blue screens where you can recover your system. My problem is something a bit different. I don't get to these screens but as soon as I change the setting and reboot the pc directly goes into boot mode from where I can either shut it down or change the setting back to use RST (then windows will boot again).

If I set it to AHCI I can boot ubuntu from a stick and start the installation process. However the problem then is, that it does not detect that windows is already installed on one of the partitions and that is why it doesn't offer me the option to install it alongside windows which I have seen in some tutorial videos.

I have no idea how to debug this as the solutions I found did not help so far. Btw the laptop is an MSI Creator 15 (if somebody has experience with that brand in particular). I wondered if there is maybe some other option I have to change?

EDIT: Because the PC is new, I have barely installed programs and have no personal data on there. So if uninstalling and reinstalling windows would be an easier option. Maybe with some changed options right from the start (I always had windows preinstalled on my devices so I have no idea how one would go about this)?

EDIT 2: I added a picture of the BIOS screen I am seeing here:

[image]

The value it was at was `Intel RST Premium With Intel Optane System Acceleration`. I then switched it to `AHCI`where I got the problems with windows not booting.

I am glad for all the help I can get, so thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to update UEFI to latest. If SSD, update its firmware. You have to install Windows AHCI driver first then change to AHCI in UEFI settings. AHCI enable - May have to unlock bitlocker if used
https://superuser.com/questions/1280141/switch-raid-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-10 &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems/1233644#1233644 or see my answer below.

Comment: If my answer, below, is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @olfred Thank you I will have a look at updating UEFI. Is there anything I have to pay attention to when getting this driver? How do I get the correct one?

Comment: See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu/282903#282903) for something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
- Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`

  - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`

  - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: This is a very detailed explanation which I have tried before, thanks. I tested it again to make sure but after changing the BIOS value Windows does not boot into safe mode but just turns off, restarts and I find myself in bios again, just like I described above. I don't know if there is anything I could be doing wrong here but the steps seem very clear

Comment: I only found solutions for this problem claiming to solve the problem without re-installing windows. Do you by any chance have such a nice description of how you could solve this problem by uninstalling windows?

Comment: @cassini This process does not require uninstalling or reinstalling Windows. Many users have followed it successfully. You might try checking your Windows installation for errors first, in an admin window, type `chkdsk /f c:`, then reboot.

Comment: The console printed `The type of the file system is NTFS. Cannot lock current drive`. Then I restarted. It started some checking and repairing process and then told me to that automatic repair could not fix the problem and I could either restart or chose advanced options. I restarted and windows booted normally. To make sure I repeated the command again. This time after the check/repair section windows booted normally. I then did the steps above again but it is still the same result

Comment: I also added a photo of my bios setting, if that might be helpful

Comment: @cassini Oh, you have Optane memory in your drive subsystem. I don't know if you can install Ubuntu in that configuration. Search here for "optane" and see what you find.

Comment: first update on this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane mentioned that one could disable optane in a preinstalled windows app. I tried this but it said in there optane was disabled and that `your system seems to be Intel optane ready but no intel optane memory modules were detected in your computer`

Comment: @cassini Good research. I assumed you had Optane because of the current BIOS setting. I don't know what's up with your computer. Sorry.

Comment: thanks anyway, I appreciate your effort a lot. Do you have an idea how to best proceed with this issue? Should I consider asking the manufacturer?

Comment: @cassini Flip the setting to AHCI and reinstall Windows. Then Ubuntu. The manufacturer won't help with Linux.

Comment: Changing to AHCI, then reinstalling Windows followed by Ubuntu worked out for me in the end. Thanks again @heynnema

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reboot windows in safe mode after the switch to AHCI?
You need to have a complete boot on AHCI at least one time.

You can configure that with msconfig on windows before switching to AHCI:
https://www.intowindows.com/4-ways-to-change-the-boot-order-in-windows-10/

Comment: So I don't know if I did it correctly: what I did was use msconfig and tick the box for safe mode. I then turned the laptop of, started and went into the bios to change to ahci. After this I can only exit bios if the pc turns of. If I boot again I have the same problem as described above and land in bios once again. Did I do something wrong there?

Comment: After bios update my sata configuration was changed from ide to ahci and after that when I booted back in Windows it showed me blue screen of death as ahci is for newer storage device. Let it be in IDE ,I have both Ubuntu and Windows working fine in dualboot@cassini and disable secure boot in bios and disable fast startup in Windows

Comment: but how did you do this so it was fine with ubuntu? I just get to the message time and time again that it is not compatible with Intel RST