# Boot from Grub sub menu and recovery mode only - Menu Assignment to Lubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, menu, recovery-mode

After a few attempts I managed to install Lubuntu 20.04 on a new Asus VivoBook 513  (Intel graphic) alongside Win10, so that the Grub boot menu appears now (Windows seems to be very obstinate in keeping Hibernate even though I was sure to have done Shot Down.  Secure boot is disabled, Hibernate too).

Grub menu  appears, thank God.
But when I select Standard Ubuntu in the main menu, only the Asus logo (belongs to the EFI BIOS) appears and keeps standing!  No booting.

But I can boot via →

```
Advanced Options for Ubuntu

    → Ubuntu with Linux 5,4,0-70  (recovery mode)
        → Recovery Menu (Wiederherstellungsmenü)    → resume :  ′startup process normal′
```

Then the login screen appears quickly and quickly the desktop. And it looks good,  screen resolution is correct, audio is working,  brightness setting and suspend doesn't.

Also I can boot from main menu → `Advanced options for Ubuntu → Ubuntu with Linux 5.4.0-70` (normal)  the system.
But it takes very much longer, there are many HUB AE and ACPI Errors (looking for hardware drivers?) (this is actually a second topic, but maybe both can be solved in one?   via grub → GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash xxxxx??") .

AND UPDATE :  After updating the system the boot process stops after all these Errors, last line: `hdaudio COD2:  unable to bind the codec`
there it stops.
Thanks for your time...

Comment: Does it also have nVidia? And which Intel chip? Some very new systems need very new kernels, drivers & support software. Or latest distribution. While I normally suggest LTS versions, you may need 20.10 or even the not yet released 21.04 which they do not support on this site, till released.Even new you may need UEFI update & if SSD, SSD firmware update. Older Vivobook. Asus Vivobook 15 Intel i5-8250 CPU
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane

Comment: @oldfred  All I can find about graphic with  `lshw` is:   
`-display UNCLAIMED
description: VGA compatible controller
 product: Intel Corporation ...`
And yes, it has SSD. The device is produced Sep. 2020

Comment: `inxi`  is giving:
`Graphics:  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6`

Comment: Is this so new it has the new Intel Xe graphics? That requires the very newest kernel & driver. llvmpipe is a low level default. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023781/graphics.html For at least the first generation or two of Xe Graphics, the long-standing Intel "i915" Direct Rendering Manager driver will be used.
A Look At Linux 5.10 + Mesa 21.0-dev On Intel "Tiger Lake" Xe Graphics Dec 2020
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.10-Mesa-21.0-Xe-Compare

Comment: Thanks @ oldfred.  In accordance with that info by [link] (https://wiki.debian.org/Mesa)
`$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL` says the CPU is used to render the graphics  instead the GPU.
But `$ glxinfo  | grep rendering` gives `direct rendering: Yes`  
I am a bit confused. Can this be the reason that the system doesnt boot from the Grub default menu Ubuntu?

Comment: and I asume in that article by  https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.10-Mesa-21.0-Xe-Compare   with 'Linux 5.8 + Mesa 21.0-dev '  the kernel is meant. is it?

Comment: The phoronix site often tests with newer kernel & drivers. It uses a ppa to get those. Later those kernels & drivers are in a distribution, but only in the latest distribution or update to a distribution, if it updates kernels. Later this month a new Ubunt comes out. It now is in Beta and you can test that if you want to see if that is the issue. If not then some boot paramater may be required. Or some setting in UEFI that is unique to your brand and maybe model system.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed now Kubuntu 21.04 and it works fine. The kernel is 5.11.0-18
Hotkeys for the screen brightness and sound, even the keyboard illumination.
It's  booting in 12 sec from Grub Bootmenu ! from SSD.