# Windows 11 partitions are not recognized in Ubuntu installer

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I bought a laptop ASUS Vivobook R465JA-EB1467W with Windows 11 on board.
I would like to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop with dual booting of Ubuntu and Windows.
The problem is that Windows partitions are not recognized in Ubuntu installer.
What I have done so far:

I made bootable USB drive with rufus. Choose GPT partition scheme.

- I have turned off "fast startup" in Windows
- turned off "Fast boot" option in BIOS (UEFI to be more precious)
- turned off "Secure boot" option in BIOS
- changed SATA mode to AHCI

But all these actions did no succeed. Below are screenshots and photos with more detailed information:

[image]

[image]

These are from Ubuntu live session:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

There are a lot of options in UEFI. Probably some of them interferes in the installing process:

[image]

Appreciate for any information

Comment: please replace rhe images that contain TEXT by a copy/paste. Images are not searchable, text is and we can copy text instead of all of us having to type notices or errors.

Comment: I would be happy to insert text directly but have no idea how to do it from the live session where I don't have access to the Internet

Comment: I thought changing to AHCI was changing the Intel RST or Optane. But check the Intel RST settings. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane

Comment: And be aware that unless you install AHCI support in Windows prior to changing the drive mode to AHCI (and disabling Intel RST) it won't boot. If it did then you didn't actually changed the mode.