# No device for boot loader installation - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb-installation

I have tried different things from the answers here, but there is still "no device for boot loader installation" when I boot from USB. This is the first time I am installing Linux.

I have Win 7 on HP Elitebook 840 and I want a dual boot (I would also say yes to replace Windows if I was sure I would be able to install Ubuntu and work)

Steps already taken:

1) Several defragmentations in Defraggler 
2) Creating a partition in Windows (35 GB) 
3) Creating again a new partition in GParted (or rather allocating it so it is recognized; Ubuntu quick start), formatting to ext4. Mount option is not available when I click on that.

Current status: 
/dev/sda1    ntfs    (boot Win)
/dev/sda2    ntfs    drive C
/dev/sda3    ext4    new partition

note: Install alongside vs replace Windows screen is actually not showing up, it goes directly to device-type-mount screen and there is nothing to choose.

Comment: If old Windows 7, then probably BIOS/MBR. But is hardware newer UEFI and you are trying to install Ubuntu in newer UEFI boot mode? If so it needs an ESP, but drive really should be gpt partitioned for UEFI install. Have you updated UEFI?

Comment: Actually, what now worked was what I tried before unsuccessfully - sudo apt-get purge dmraid.   

Unfortunately, now  I'm stuck on a different issue. The installation was allegedly successful, so I restarted, booted again from USB (this where I am trying to get - to have the dual OS option when I turn my PC on) and it started the installation process again with the same issue as in the beginning.

Comment: Do you then have RAID/Intel RST on in UEFI settings for drives? That needs to be AHCI, as desktop does not install correctly with that. It used to not even start install, but now issue seems to be mostly grub install. If dual booting with Windows you have to first add AHCI driver to Windows or it will not boot with AHCI on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148120/ubuntu-18-0x-not-detecting-windows-ssd-during-installation & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on#963100

Comment: I tried to change it from RAID to AHCI in BIOS before and yes - Windows wouldn't load. It just keeps restarting. OK, so now it seems to be working. Thanks a lot!
sudo apt-get purge dmraid and switching to AHCI.