# Can't install Ubuntu RST and Intel Optane problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have used dual boot on my old laptop, but this one uses Intel Optane and RST (Rapid Storage Technology) and changing it to AHCI, which is what my old laptop was set to by default gives me the bluescreen of death. I have some experience with Linux, I mainly use kali in a persistence usb but it is laggy at times and like the look of ubuntu.

Comment: **First, a WARNING**. 1) Intel Optane is tightly coupled with the SSD/HDD, and acts in such a way to speed up Windows operations. 2) Ubuntu won't install  on disk systems configured with RST (RAID). Here's a [procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems/1233644#1233644) to fix the RST problem. **BUT** in this case, because of the Optane, it **MAY** break your Windows system... so have good backups of your important data. You'll probably end up separating the Optane from the SSD/HDD, and installing Ubuntu on the Optane.

Comment: You need AHCI drivers in Windows.  See heynnema link first. Older instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148120/ubuntu-18-0x-not-detecting-windows-ssd-during-installation & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on#963100

Comment: Thanks, i forgot the drivers, no wonder windows crashed when i changed it to ahci. Also i figured i can reinstall windows after ubuntu, i have an ubuntu database server that has all my backups so once ubuntu is installed i will reinstall windows. I will try the drivers first. Thanks very much.

Comment: Is there still no solution for this to boot ubuntu with Intel RST RAID mode enabled? It's been well over a year.